# admob interstitial ad issue?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-admob

I am developing app using cordova phonegap android plateform.

I install user ads plugin in my app, everything is working fine but in device moto G the interstitial ad is opening even after I leave my app.

Please let me know if any of you have face this issue and fixed it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please see documentation here (I've just udated it right now): https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/showInterstitialAd

> Note: Interstitials may be shown even if the android app is in
>   background. For this reason it is recommended to stop banners and 
>   interstitials and reload then when onPause and onResume events 
>   are detected.

For this reason, you should listen for `onPause` and `onResume` events:

```
var isAppForeground = true;

function onAdLoaded(e) {
  if (isAppForeground) {
    if (e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE.INTERSTITIAL) {
      admob.showInterstitialAd();
    }
  }
}

function onPause() {
  if (isAppForeground) {
    admob.destroyBannerView();
    isAppForeground = false;
  }
}

function onResume() {
  if (!isAppForeground) {
    setTimeout(admob.requestInterstitialAd, 1);
    isAppForeground = true;
  }
}

// optional, in case respond to events
function registerAdEvents() {
  document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdLoaded, onAdLoaded);

  document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
  document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
}

function initAds() {
  if (admob) {
    var adPublisherIds = {
      ios : {
        banner : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",
        interstitial : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII"
      },
      android : {
        banner : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",
        interstitial : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII"
      }
    };

    var admobid = (/(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? adPublisherIds.android : adPublisherIds.ios;

    admob.setOptions({
      publisherId:          admobid.banner,
      interstitialAdId:     admobid.interstitial,
      autoShowInterstitial: false
    });

    registerAdEvents();

  } else {
    alert('AdMobAds plugin not ready');
  }
}

function onDeviceReady() {
  document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
  initAds();

  // request an interstitial
  admob.requestInterstitialAd();
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```